# Visual Studio shows error "Unreachable code" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I'm working in an API with NODE, but at the moment of are writing VC shows error "Unreachable code", on the next code:

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt')
const _ =require('lodash')
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const {validationResult} = require('express-validator')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
//Esto es para obtener el error de la  base de datos, se puede personalizar para hacerlo amigable.
const { errorHandler} =require('../helpers/dbErrorHandling')
//el siguiente const se usará para enviar correos
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')

const pool = require('../database/connection')








exports.AuthController = (req, res) => { 
    const email = (req.params.email);
    let sql = `select User_email from user where User_email = ${email}`;
    const mail = poo.query(sql);

    if(email.length = 0) {
        return res.json({
            code: 404,
            message: "Equipo no encontrado",
            data: [],
        })

    }else{
        return res.json({
            code: 404,
            message: "",
        })

    //generate token

    *const token = jwt.sign({
        email
    }, 
    process.env.ACCES_TOKEN_SECRET,{
        expiresIn: '1440m'
    }
    )

    const emailData = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
      to: email,
      subject: 'Account activation link',
      html: `
                <h1>Please use the following to activate your account</h1>
                <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/users/activate/${token}</p>
                <hr />
                <p>This email may containe sensetive information</p>
                <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}</p>
            `
    }

    }

}*
```

The content that is not receiving me is whats is between " * ", so if know what it's happened I'll be grateful for an explanation.

Comment: Do you mean *unreachable code* where you mention *unresearch code*? That message means the code can never run.

Comment: @seyeredg : you got a comment and an answer, usually you should leave some feedback if it was helpful or not, and accept/upvote an answer that solved/answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean *unreachable code* where you mention *unresearch code*? That message means the code can never run.

In your case you `return` from your function on both the `if` and `else` branch. The compiler is pretty smart about this.

```
if(email.length = 0) {
    return res.json({                    /* returns, exiting function */
        code: 404,
        message: "Equipo no encontrado",
        data: [],
    })
} else {
    return res.json({                    /* also returns, exiting function */
        code: 404,
        message: "",
    })
}
/* execution can never get here, so code below is unreachable. */
```

You want `if (email.length === 0)`. `if (email.length = 0)` fails at runtime because `length` is a read-only property of a string. You cannot put a `0` value into it.

There is a [Spanish-language pack for Visual Studio Code here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-CEINTL.vscode-language-pack-es). You may find it helpful, especially if you are just starting to learn.